# Unity spawns 2 gameObjects and not one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spawn one random item inside an empty `GameObject`. But for some reason some times it spawns 2 specific prefabs instead of one and i can't figure out where exactly the problem is.

**My spawner script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private GameObject dogeCoindPrefab, rockCoinPrefab, slimePrefab;
    [System.Obsolete]
    void Start()
    {
        int itemNumber = Random.RandomRange(0,3);
        switch (itemNumber)
        {
            case 0:
                spawnGameObject(dogeCoindPrefab);
                break;
            case 1:
                spawnGameObject(rockCoinPrefab);
                break;
            case 2:
                spawnGameObject(slimePrefab);
                break;
            default:
                spawnGameObject(dogeCoindPrefab);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void spawnGameObject(GameObject selectedGameObject) 
    {
        Instantiate(selectedGameObject, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your function calling only 1 time also you need to be sure about your prefabs contain only one object. Because your code seems correct.

Comment: @HTugsadK As you can see i'm calling the spawn function inside start method, so it's called one time when the onject is created.

Comment: Your scripts looks correct, Make sure that, you attached it on only  one `GameObject` in your scene.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok.
Go check the script has assigned in two gameObjects.
You may try `Debug.Log()` function in `Start()` to check this.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems ok, make sure you didn't add a script to your gameObject twice. Other than that you can try to debug, and set breakpoint in spawnGameObject() to see if it's called twice, and check callstack maybe